# How to count Kernel evaluations then call a function on every nth evaluation

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, kernel, user-interface, persistence

On every nth (2) evaluation `autoEval` should invoke a function `check[]`. The thing which is supposed to listen for all `Notebook Kernel Evaluation`-s is this  `CellEvaluationFunction :> (check[])`. I also tried and failed with `SetOptions[nb,$Pre:>(check[])];` and `SetOptions[nb,CellProlog:>(check[])];` and `SetOptions[nb,CellEpilog:>(check[])];`. All producecd same message that evaluation symbols given are
not options of notebook object. Please help!

I prefer using `TaggingRules` for keeping persistent values but I could not get those to work either. If you think you have a better solution I'm all ears.

```
autoEval[ ] := NotebookAutoBackup[2]
autoEval[ n_Integer /; n > 0, objname_String : "autoback", 
   objloc_ : "Local"] :=  Block[{nb = EvaluationNotebook, x = 0},
   check[] := (++x; 
     If[x == n, (Echo@n; Print["check[]"]; 
       PersistentSymbol[objname, objloc] = 0), 
      PersistentSymbol[objname, objloc] = x]; Echo@x);
   (*SetOptions[nb,CellEvaluationFunction:>(check[])];*)
   CellEvaluationFunction :> (check[])
   ];
autoEval[]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `$Pre` or `$Post` together with a global variable to keep count of how many times a cell is evaluated:

First you would initialize count and e.g. `$Pre` in s separate cell:

```
count=0;
$Pre = (If[EvenQ[count++], Print["checking"]]; #) &;
```

Then the first cell evaluated will not print "checking". However, the second time you evaluate a cell "checking" is printed. This also happens every even number of times.

Comment: i really appreciate your help but i hesitate to use system-wide Kernel sniffers as they may interfere with other notebook tasks or projects. That's why I selected the given symbols as they can be set at the notebook level.

Comment: @DanielJHuber please disregard previous comment. although my example code shows n=2. This small value was given for expediency for testing function. The real-world value will be an arbitrarily selected positive integer probably less than 12. It will ultimately be a function that automatically creates a backup of `InputNotebook` at every nth Kernel evaluation. So how can we modify your solution for every nth evaluation?

Comment: Simply write: `If[Mod[count++,n]==0,....]`

Comment: @DanierlHuber thank you so much. you were very helpful. If you don';t mind would you have  a look at another similar question I posted since? I;'ll tag your name to it if you dont mind.

Comment: Sorry, I can not see your question.

Comment: here it is...

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262623/how-to-reset-an-event-counter-to-zero-after-every-nth-evaluation-while-using-exp?noredirect=1#comment654019_262623