# How to reset an event counter to zero after every nth evaluation while using Experimental`ValueFunction to observe for value changes in counter

Tags: event-detection, eventhandler, counter

#### Synopsis

Below serves as a skeleton for a function that will track number of occurrences of a particular notebook event. The nth event will trigger a function call. After which the counter symbol must be reset `eval=0` so that function can be called again on next nth event.

The event will automatically increment counter `eval` which is wrapped in an observer function `` Experimental`ValueFunction[eval] :=f `` which will perform a function call if a condition is met and reset counter when `eval == n`.

#### Problem With Code

Well it doesn't quite work. It throws an occassioanal error `$RecursionLimit...` and fails to reset `eval = 0`. Please share your insight.

#### Exhibit 1: Buggy Code

```
Quiet@Remove@"Global`*";
n = 3;
resetOnNth[n_Integer : 6] := Block[{},
   eval = 0;
   Needs["Experimental`"];
   Experimental`ValueFunction[eval] := 
    If[eval === n, eval = 0, Echo[eval, "eval \[Rule]"]];
   Return@eval
   ];

resetOnNth[n];

(* event simulator: 2 loops of 3 events *)
Do[++eval, n, 2];
```

#### Exhibit 2: Expected Output - If Good

(Edited: was {0,1,2,0,1,2})

```
>> eval ->  1
>> eval ->  2
>> eval ->  3
>> eval ->  1
>> eval ->  2
>> eval ->  3
```

#### Exhibit 3: Actual Output - Bad

```
>> eval ->  6
>> eval ->  0
>> eval ->  0
>> eval ->  1
>> eval ->  2

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of eval===3.

>> eval ->  4
>> eval ->  5
```

Comment: @DanielHuber  do you think you may have some insight on this?

Comment: At first sight, this looks a bit of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you perhaps elaborate more on the actual problem you are trying to solve? Can you not – instead of ``++eval`` and complications with ``Experimental`ValueFunction`` – simply use something like ``incrementEval[]``, where ``incrementEval[] := If[eval === n, eval = 0, Echo[eval, "eval \[Rule]"]; eval++];``?

Comment: If you reset "eval" to zero inside ""Experimental`ValueFunction"" , you are again triggering "Experimental`ValueFunction" again, what leads to an infinite recursion.

Comment: Avoid this `ValueFunction` nonsense and use an UpValue:  ```eval /: PreIncrement[eval] /; eval == 3 := (eval = 0)```

Comment: Using the hint from Jason you woul write: `..eval /: PreIncrement[eval] /; eval == 3 := (eval = 0)
resetOnNth[n_Integer : 6] := Block[{}, eval = 0;
   Needs["Experimental`"];
   Experimental`ValueFunction[eval] := 
    If[eval =!= n, Echo[eval, "eval \[Rule]"]];
   Return@eval];..`

Comment: @DanielHuber im not sure i understand completely. do you mind putting your solution in an Answer? ill be sure to Upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ordered :)

```
Quiet@Remove@"Global`*";
n = 3;
eval /: PreIncrement[eval] /; eval == n := (eval = 0);

resetOnNth[n_Integer : 6] := 
  Block[{}, eval = 0; 
   Experimental`ValueFunction[eval] := 
    If[Mod[eval, n] =!= 0, Echo[eval, "eval \[Rule]"]]; Return@eval];

resetOnNth[n];

Do[++eval, n, 2];
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insight and expertise with me You probably saved me at least a few hair-pulling days of intense research and reading and yelling that infamous 4-letter word out loud in my office every time i hit a wall of confusion or misunderstanding.

Comment: @DaniellHuber ive been studying your solution. i had no idea what this was: `eval /: PreIncrement[eval] /; eval == n := (eval = 0);` but after a quick search in docs reveals it as a `TagSetDelayed` which I  have never done before. I intend to to learn more about it, thank you again for your elegant solution.

Comment: `PreIncrement[eval] /; eval == n` means the pattern only matches if eval==n. `eval /:` means that the assignment should be stored as upvalue under the name "eval" and not "Preincrement" what would give an error, because "Preincrement " is protected

Comment: after a closer i look j did notice that your solution was still slightly off. the . order of the output is reversed and one short `{2,1,2,1 }`. should be `{1,2,3,1,2,3}`. im not sure if i know how to correct it but ill give a good try maybe by tomorrow night.

Comment: Please view answer I posted. I got about as far as I could get. My refactored solution is almost there.

Answer (score 0):

#### My Almost There Solution

##### What Changed and More on Final Goal

Based on very valuable near-solutions by Daniel Huber and Jason B. Function name was `resetOnNth`. Changed to `observer` to better reflect its purpose of only initializing `Global` functions and symbols that observe Kernel evaluations and react accordingly. Eventually the `Do` loop will be replaced by `$Pre = on Kernel evaluation eval++`. The purpose of `Echo@eval` is to monitor the performance of Kernel counter `eval` during development. When we get this running smoothly those will no longer be needed.

Changed `PreIncrement` to `Increment` for no real reason. Also changed `Mod[...]` to `eval < n` as it seems to work better at least for now. Added `Print[...]` as a placeholder for intended function `NotebookAutoBackup` to `*Upvalue` so that it occurs when `eval==n` which is every nth Kernel evaluation. And finally changed `n` to `$n` to make certain there is no shadowing and now 3 running loops to better observe the pattern `eval` counter makes. More is explained in the code as comments.

I wish to add that my heart is not set on any of these changes. I am open to anything that might fix it.

##### Exhibit 1: Refactored - Almost Works

```
Quiet@Remove@"Global`*";
 ClearSystemCache[];

(* everything moved inside observer *)
(* it only needs to evaluate once *)
(* because it only initializes globals *)
observer[n_Integer : 6] := Block[{},
   eval = 0;
   eval /: 
    Increment[eval] /; 
     eval == n := (Print@
      Row[{"{n,eval} \[Rule] ", {n, eval}, 
        ": placeholder for NotebookAutoBackup[]"}]; eval = 0);
   Needs["Experimental`"];
   Experimental`ValueFunction[eval] := 
    If[eval < n, Echo[eval, "eval \[Rule]"]];
   eval
   ];

$n = 3;
observer[$n];
Column[{Row[{"$n: ", $n}], Row[{"eval: ", eval}]}]

(* simulate Kernel evaluations *)
Do[eval++, $n 3];
```

##### Exhibit 2: Intended Output

```
>> eval ->  1
>> eval ->  2
{n,eval} -> {3,3}: placeholder for NotebookAutoBackup[]

>> eval ->  1
>> eval ->  2
{n,eval} -> {3,3}: placeholder for NotebookAutoBackup[]

>> eval ->  1
>> eval ->  2
{n,eval} -> {3,3}: placeholder for NotebookAutoBackup[]
```

##### Exhibit 3: Actual Output

Notice how the counter `eval` now runs in the correct direction and even performs the most important function when `eval == n`. In fact it would run pretty decent now. Problem is that is not good enough for publishing content at Mathematica Function Repository. It has a quirky start and performs intended function on 4th evaluation not 3rd. The end loop doesnt complete but that doesn't concern much because I like the pattern it takes. Run the actual code to see more inspectors (not shown below) inserted into it.

```
>> eval ->  1

>> eval ->  0
>> eval ->  1
>> eval ->  2
{n,eval} -> {3,3}: placeholder for NotebookAutoBackup[]

>> eval ->  0
>> eval ->  1
>> eval ->  2
{n,eval} -> {3,3}: placeholder for NotebookAutoBackup[]

>> eval ->  0
```

Comment: So the goal is to execute a given kernel command on every third evaluation? That should be easy enough to do with `$Pre` without using this `ValueFunction`

Comment: Something like `Module[{counter = 0}, $Pre = (If[Divisible[++counter, 3], Print["we are saving now"]]; #) &]` would do the trick, if that is what you are going for.

Comment: Remove the first `eval = 0;` in "observer". And iInitialize eval to 1.

Comment: @JasonB. well it needs to evaluate for any nth positive integer selected by end-user but i <3 where youre going with this. Does this look like it would work? `AutoBackup[n_Integer?PositiveQ]:=Module[{counter = 0}, $Pre = (If[Divisible[++counter,n], NotebookBackup[]]; #) &]`

Comment: That looks right to me

Comment: @JasonB. i speculate that there had to be a simple lightweight solution like the one you proposed (which i intend to implement). i am still new to Mathematica so sometimes i like try new things even if they are not most practical solution. i find that I learn more from such trial and error than from always implementing fire and forget cookbook solutions. this approach was my attempt at implementing the observer design pattern popular in OOP javascript frameworks (where i learned it) for communicating states and data between various layers of client and backend. anyway thanks again. :)